# Adding Disclosure Indicator to map pins iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios5, mkmapview, mapkit

I can't seem to be able to add a disclosure button to my map annotations.

I implemented the MKMapViewDelegate to my view controller as well. What am I missing?

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *mapPin = nil;
    if(annotation != map.userLocation) 
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"defaultPin";
        mapPin = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if (mapPin == nil )
            mapPin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];

        mapPin.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        mapPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;

    }
    return mapPin;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code should work but check the following:

- Is the map view's `delegate` property set?  Declaring that the view controller implements the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol does not actually tell the map view which object is implementing the delegate methods.  In code, do `map.delegate = self;` or in IB connect the `delegate` outlet to File's Owner.
- Is the annotation's `title` property set to non-blank?  If the `title` is blank, no callout will show.

Also, unrelated but, when the dequeue returns an annotation view, you should update its `annotation` property to the current annotation (it might have been used for another annotation previously).  Additionally, unless you're using ARC, you should also `autorelease` the view.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *mapPin = nil;
    if(annotation != map.userLocation) 
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"defaultPin";
        mapPin = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if (mapPin == nil )
        {
            mapPin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                         reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];
            mapPin.canShowCallout = YES;
            UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            mapPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;
        }
        else
            mapPin.annotation = annotation;

    }
    return mapPin;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anna, problem was the delegate. I forgot to properly update it.